# AtomicInteger is not working properly in java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I am having writer and reader threads though I use AtomicBoolean and AtomicInteger I could see duplicate values in the reader thread, please help me to find what's wrong with my code.

```
package automic;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
public class AutomicTest {

    public volatile AtomicBoolean isStopped = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    public AtomicInteger  count =  new AtomicInteger(0);
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        AutomicTest test = new AutomicTest();
        
        Thread writerThread = new Thread(() ->{
            while(!test.isStopped.get()) {
                test.count.incrementAndGet();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        
        
        Thread readerThread = new Thread(() ->{
            while(!test.isStopped.get()) {
                System.out.println("Counter :"+test.count.get());
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        
        
        writerThread.start();
        readerThread.start();
        
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        
        test.isStopped.getAndSet(true);
        
        writerThread.join();
        readerThread.join();
    }
}



Counter :1
Counter :2
Counter :3 // duplicate
Counter :3 // duplicate
Counter :4
Counter :5
Counter :7
Counter :8
Counter :9
Counter :10
Counter :11
Counter :12 // duplicate
Counter :12 // duplicate
Counter :13
Counter :15 // duplicate
Counter :15 // duplicate
Counter :17
Counter :18
Counter :19
Counter :20
Counter :21
Counter :22
Counter :23
Counter :24
Counter :25
Counter :26
Counter :27
Counter :28
Counter :29
Counter :30
Counter :31
Counter :32
Counter :33
Counter :34
Counter :35
Counter :36
Counter :37
Counter :38
Counter :39
Counter :40
```

Comment: So the reader acted twice between the writer's increment? Why do you think that's not "working properly"

Comment: thanks for reply, from my understanding AutomicInteger will give always synched value between two threads if they are(reader and writer), but here I see different

Comment: Define _synched_. `get()` is just retrieving the current value it sees in the `AtomicInteger`.

Comment: The problem is not that that `AtomicInteger` does not work. It does. What you see is a simple thread weaving issue. Waiting for 100 ms does not mean you'll schedule the threads in an exact tick-tock way. Depending on your OS, the time can have a worse granularity than 1 ms. Even if it did not, a lot can happen in a single ms, and the threads are likely simply running in the same ms, sometimes swapping order. If you want them to sync in a tick-tock way, you need to use a `CountDownLatch` or something similar.

Comment: The two threads do not necessarily run synchronzied. Imagine that the 1st thread has a head start of 150 milliseconds. This would mean that the inner loop of the 1st thread is (most probably) executed twice before the 2nd thread executes its first iteration.

Comment: You can also see that after the duplicates you see skipped numbers. That's because the threads flipped their order again, and the reader "missed" one beat. This is normal, welcome to multithreading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two big take-aways from this are that:

- `Thread.sleep(100)` does not mean "Sleep for 100 ms, exactly to the nanosecond". It's a little less exact, depends on the granularity and accuracy of the internal OS clock, on native thread scheduling, other tasks running on the computer. Even the sleep-wakeup cycle takes some (a surprisingly high) amount of time.
- Atomics are good when multiple threads cooperate independently. If you need them to be somehow dependent, and/or react to other threads' actions, atomics are not what you want. You'll need to use an actual synchronization mechanism.

Therefore, you cannot use `sleep()` and atomics to schedule two threads to run in a perfectly balanced tick-tock cycle.

This happens in your code:

1. Writer thread writes value 1 at time 100, then goes to sleep.
2. Reader thread reads value 1 at time 100, then goes to sleep. They can both easily run on the same ms, on a multicore system they can even run at exactly the same time, and they probably do.
3. Reader wakes up at time 200.0 and reads value 1 again.
4. Writer wakes up at time 200.02 and writes value 2. Oops, we just got a duplicate.

Do note that the threads can even flip back, in that case you'll see a missing number in the sequence, and occasionally you do. To balance the threads to run in a perfect A-B-A-B scheme you can do e.g. something like this:

```java
public class AutomicTest {

    private volatile boolean isStopped = false;

    private final CyclicBarrier barrier = new CyclicBarrier(2);
    private int count = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        AutomicTest test = new AutomicTest();

        Thread writerThread = new Thread(() -> {
            while (!test.isStopped) {
                test.count++;
                try {
                    test.barrier.await();
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException | BrokenBarrierException ignored) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    break;
                }
            }
        });

        Thread readerThread = new Thread(() -> {
            while (!test.isStopped) {
                try {
                    test.barrier.await();
                    System.out.println("Counter: " + test.count);
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException | BrokenBarrierException ignored) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    break;
                }
            }
        });

        writerThread.start();
        readerThread.start();

        Thread.sleep(4000);

        test.isStopped = true;

        writerThread.join();
        readerThread.join();
    }

}
```

The key here is a [`CyclicBarrier`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html) which is:

> A synchronization aid that allows a set of threads to all wait for
> each other to reach a common barrier point. CyclicBarriers are useful
> in programs involving a fixed sized party of threads that must
> occasionally wait for each other. The barrier is called *cyclic*
> because it can be re-used after the waiting threads are released.

In this case the barrier is set up to have two synchronized parties - the Writer and the Reader:

- The Writer first writes its value, then waits for all parties to arrive to the barrier (in other words, it waits for the Reader to read the value).
- The Reader first waits for all parties to arrive to the barrier (in other words, it waits for the Writer to write a new value), only then reads the value.

In this scheme, the `count` value's visibility is enforced by the `CyclicBarrier`, so you do not even need an `AtomicInteger` here. More specifically:

> Actions in a thread prior to calling `await()` *happen-before* [...]
> actions following a successful return from the corresponding `await()`
> in other threads.

Oh, and the `isStopped` also does not need an `AtomicBoolean`, a `volatile` is enough. But it will work either way. Sorry, I understand this was supposed to be a task to practice atomics, but they're not a good tool if you need the threads to wait for each other.

---

<sub>Footnote: The mechanism above is still not *exactly* correct when you remove the `sleep()` calls. The reason for that is that once released, the Reader races with the Writer on the next loop iteration. To fix that, the Writer must wait for the previous Reader to finish and the Reader must wait for its Writer to finish. This can be achiever by using a second barrier or perhaps a [`Phaser`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Phaser.html) which I intentionally did not use in the example above as it is more advanced and you need to learn CyclicBarriers and CountDownLatches before moving on to Phasers. Also the shutdown mechanism needs to be tuned. Good luck!</sub>

EDIT: I actually wrote the no-`sleep()` double-Phaser solution and found out that it is much easier to read (if you do not care about long-running-task interruption which you normally should!) and *much* faster than an equivalent CyclicBarrier solution. So we both learned something today. Here it is:

```java
public class AutomicTest {

    private volatile boolean isStopped = false;

    private final Phaser valueWritten = new Phaser(2);
    private final Phaser valueRead = new Phaser(2);
    private int count = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        AutomicTest test = new AutomicTest();

        Thread writerThread = new Thread(() -> {
            while (!test.isStopped) {
                // wait for the previous value to be read
                test.valueRead.arriveAndAwaitAdvance();
                test.count++;
                // acknowledge the write
                test.valueWritten.arrive();
            }
        });

        Thread readerThread = new Thread(() -> {
            while (!test.isStopped) {
                // wait for the value to be written
                test.valueWritten.arriveAndAwaitAdvance();
                System.out.println("Counter: " + test.count);
                // acknowledge the read
                test.valueRead.arrive();
            }
        });

        writerThread.start();
        readerThread.start();
        test.valueRead.arrive(); // start the writer

        Thread.sleep(4000);

        test.isStopped = true;
        test.valueRead.forceTermination();
        test.valueWritten.forceTermination();

        writerThread.join();
        readerThread.join();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was a great correction and detailed explanation.

Comment: @sunleo You're welcome! I just added a no-sleep() solution, too, because I learned that it can actually look nice *and* be very fast.